# Mini tasks flow bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where i need to define a flow of task which comprise of 4 mini task . Above that i need to show end user at which mini task he is. For this i am using image tags for every task.

```
 <img>1</img>
 <img>2</img>
 <img>3</img>
 <img>4</img>
```

Is there any other way to do this , like relating it by css or jquery but not by using image. Any idea is appriciated. 
Thanks in advance.

[image: images of 4 steps taks]

Comment: You need to display like the image without using img tag?

Comment: `<img>1</img>` isn't valid HTML. But yes, if you need to make boxes that look like that using only CSS, it's certainly possible.

Comment: Ya not using image at all. Either tabular format or div styles , anything using css style.

Comment: above image tag is not valid i know its just an example of what i am using...

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is pretty basic CSS. Make a div that has the correct height, width, border, text-align, padding, margin and background-color attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something Like this(Lets assume first 2 tasks are completed!):

HTML:

```
<div class='project'>
  <div class='task completed taskName1 '></div>
  <div class='task completed taskName2 '></div>
  <div class='task current taskName3 '></div>
  <div class='task taskName4 '></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.project {
  /*project styles here...*/
}

.task {
  /*task styles here...
  ...default styles*/
}

.task.completed {
  /*completed task styles here...
   override .task styles to show completed
*/
}

.task.current {
  /*completed task styles here...
   override .task styles to show current
*/
}

.taskNameX {
  /*use task specific styles here*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace your images with `<div>`s and use `background-image` (or `background-color` if you need a simple fill) css rule:

HTML:

```
<div class="task">1</div>
<div class="task">2</div>
<div class="task">3</div>
<div class="task">4</div>
```

CSS:

```
.task {
    /* image */
    background-image: url('/path/to/image');
    /* or color */
    background-color: #FF0000;
    /* or both */
    background: url('/path/to/image') no-repeat 0 0 #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for this kind of stuff, the JQuery UI CSS framework is rich enough to meet most of basic web application.

You can simply define a layout for your tasks labels like

```
.tasklabel{
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
}
```

Also, you have the [Themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) from JQuery UI where you can customize your theme and test it with your app without any changes to your code.
I made a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6gdbt/) that you can start with.